# What is the jQuery equivalent of @media screen and (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:747px)

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to wrap these elements

```
<div class="nav_menu"></div>
<div clss="logo_wrapper"></div>
```

on screen sizes between 1000px and 747px. So i would like it to become this:

```
<div class="menu-logo-wrapper">
    <div class="nav_menu"></div>
    <div clss="logo_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

I was a bunch of questions about doing just min or just max width on jQuery, but I have no idea how to combine the two.

Just to be sure I'm doing the other part right, the wrap jQuery I use is:

```
$('.mobile_menu_button, .logo_wrapper').wrapAll( "<div class='menu-logo-wrapper'></div>" );
```

Comment: Why not just always wrap them and style them with @media respective of the two sizes.  It's be generally easier to do that in the long run (especially if someone sizes the browser viewport smaller then larger...)

Comment: because somehow the html is different for screen size over 1000px. I can't explain it why but when I'm between 1000px and 747px my browser inspector show these two elements next to each other, and when I'm on any other size there are other elements in between. This screws with my flexbox :(

Answer (score 3):

You can always use windows width to add and remove classes or dynamically change the UI inside conditions. Here is the example code.

```
if($(window).width() < 1000 && $(windows).width > 747)
{
  // write something here 
  $( "#idOfYourClass" ).addClass( "your new class" );

}
elseif($(window).width() < 747)
{
  //do something else
}
else { 
 //  $( "#idOfYourClass" ).removeClass( "your new class" ); or maybe something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doesn't seem to work with $('.mobile_menu_button, .logo_wrapper').wrapAll( "<div class='logo-nav-wrapper'></div>" );  however

Comment: It should have work. Can you please share your code?

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's - if($(window).width() < 1000 && $(windows).width > 747)
{
  // write something here 
  $( "#idOfYourClass" ).addClass( "your new class" );
$('.mobile_menu_button, .logo_wrapper').wrapAll( "<div class='logo-nav-wrapper'></div>" );
}
else
{
  //do something else
}

Comment: I think there might be already jQuery on those elements, because the html markup changes between screen sizes 1000 and 747, that's why I don't want to wrap them in all screen sizes

Comment: @JohnHolliday I've made a code pen example for you. In which you can see it is working. You should've checked that your jquery is working properly and also make sure wrapAll() isn't working by checking your console in the browser. Here is the example for you. https://codepen.io/waleedbinkhalid/pen/aRvWqP

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following, and you're done....

```
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1000px) and (min-width:747px)').matches) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering. If i'm wrapping elements under the "if", do i just leave the "else" empty?

Comment: thanks. I have the following (but unfortunately doesn't work) - function whats_position() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1000px) and (min-width:747px)').matches) {
        $j('.mobile_menu_button, .logo_wrapper').wrapAll('<div class="logo-nav-wrapper"></div>');
    } else {
    }
}

Comment: if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1000px) and (min-width:747px)').matches) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
use this only, i think you've not called function whats_position();

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( thanks for taking the time tho

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery Media Query works for me. Hope this works for you as well

Code:

```
  if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 747px) and (max-width:1000px) ')) {
           /*Your Code Here*/
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time man. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: what would to like to do when it toggles the media query? Maybe I can help

Comment: I would like to wrap the elements. Essentially this is the code I tried out  if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 747px) and (max-width:1000px) ')) {
          $('.mobile_menu_button, .logo_wrapper').wrapAll( "<div class='menu-logo-wrapper'></div>" );
        }